# Get row index from DataFrame row

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Is it possible to get the row number (i.e. "the ordinal position of the index value") of a `DataFrame` row without adding an extra row that contains the row number (the index can be arbitrary, i.e. even a MultiIndex)?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6]})
>>> result = df[df.a > 3]
>>> result.iloc[0]
a    4
Name: 2, dtype: int64
# but how can I get the original row index of iloc[0] in df?
```

I could have done `df['row_index'] = range(len(df))` which would maintain the original row number, but I am wondering if Pandas has a built-in way of doing this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Access the `.name` attribute and use `get_loc`:

```
In [10]:
df.index.get_loc(result.iloc[0].name)

Out[10]:
2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this refers to the original index. Try: `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6]}, index=[4, 3, 7, 1, 5, 9]);result = df[df.a > 3];result.iloc[0].name` which returns `7`.

Comment: sorry what are you after exactly? the ordinal position of the index value?

Comment: Yes, sorry "row number" may have been misleading.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I think it should to be `df.index.get_loc(result.index[0])` if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: `result.index[0]` is the same as `result.iloc[0].name` the difference here is that you're explicitly accessing the first index element, whilst the latter is accessing the first element's index value

Comment: To display the index given a row: `r = df.iloc[n]`  then `print(r.name)`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking this from a different side:

```
for r in df.itertuples():
    getattr(r, 'Index')
```

Where df is the data frame. May be you want to use a conditional to get the index when a condition are met.